# How do I link correctly when a file(extensions removed) and a folder have the same name?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, directory

So here's the problem I've been facing.

I have to link to a file which has the same name as a folder on my server. Normally it wouldn't have been a problem, but since I have removed extensions it hasnt been working.

The file: privacy-policy.php
Folder: privacy-policy

I have removed the .php extension using .htaccess, using the code which I will list below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

When I click on the link hxxp://domain.com/privacy-policy it takes me to hxxp://domain.com/privacy-policy/ which is the folder. I want this link to take me to the file hxxp://domain.com/privacy-policy of which the extension have been removed.

I tried turning off DirectorySlash but it din't work.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.
Regards,
Vinith Almeida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need `DirectorySlash Off`.
2. Remove first `RewriteCond`

Your rule will be like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out. I copied the lines to my .htaccess but the problem persists. Clicking on the link still takes me to hxxp://domain.com/privacy-policy/

Comment: See the edit. You need `DirectorySlash Off` as well. Make sure to test in a different browser to avoid caching.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot Anubhava. I had been trying to find a solution for that since morning. Now I'm off to study about what those commands mean line by line. Thanks again.